# Gui exceptio container

Tags: java, user-interface

i have this problem:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    adding container's parent to itself

this is my class :

```
 package simplechat;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;


 public class Gui {
    public Gui(){
         JFrame fMain=new JFrame("Chat");
         Container main=new Container();
         main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         fMain.setContentPane(main);
         fMain.add(main);
         JPanel utenti=new JPanel();
         JPanel chat=new JPanel();
         utenti.setBackground(Color.red);
         utenti.setSize(150, 500);
         chat.setBackground(Color.green);
         utenti.setSize(350, 500);
         main.add(chat);
         main.add(utenti);
         main.setSize(500,500);
         main.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

and i have another class who call gui() method:

```
package simplechat;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleChat extends Frame {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Gui();
    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: remove `fMain.add(main);`

Comment: but why i can't see anything when i execute it ?

Comment: Put `fMain.setContentPane(main);` as the last statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple:
You set a container as contentpane for a frame and afterwards add the container to the frame. Some basics on how a `JFrame` works: all components that are added to a frame are actually added to its contentpane. When you add the container to the frame, you actually add a container to itself.

Comment: ok i change it  and now it works thanks  im new in Object Oriented Programming